# How can I pass the parent to use in the JOptionPane that is inside a common method?

Tags: java, swing

I have a  JFrame with 2 buttons.

Each of the buttons displays a dialog specific to that button:  `JDialog A` and `JDialog B`.  Each of these dialogs use a class with method M.  Inside Method M, I display a `JOptionPane`.

I tried passing the dialogs as components, but that did not work.  I can't use `null` in the `JOptionPane` since I need it on top.

How can I pass the parent dialog (`A` or `B`) to be used in the `JOptionPane`?

Comment: is only text is differ in A and B dialog ??

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work? (Show your code.) The obvious solution here is to pass the JDialog to the method which displays the JOptionPane, but since you say that didn't work there must be a problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The A and B dialogs are completely different, so it is not a matter of just changing the text dynamically and hard coding the parent in the JOptionPane.

Comment: ok plz show your code

Comment: _"but that did not work."_ In which way it did not work, what happened? CPU rejected to execute instructions? :)

Comment: The JOptionBox was not displayed.

Comment: So, you invoked `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, message)` and option pane did not appear? When you debug it, does the thread stop at this line?

Comment: There are two cases for what happens.  If I hardcode JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(A, message), it works.  If I pass A in as a Dialog or Component parameter, then JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(paramA, message) does not work and the thread halts.

Comment: My problem has been solved.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by reviewing the comments, especially from @Radiodef.  The problem was that my object was getting corrupted by another thread so it only worked if I did not pass the object and hard-coded it instead.